# Invalid route component in new VueJs Project

Tags: vue.js

I'm working on a Vue.js project and encountered an error that says "Error: Invalid route component." I'm having trouble figuring out the root cause of this issue. Can someone please help me diagnose and resolve it?

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import Home from '../views/Home.vue' 
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "home",
    component: "Home",
  },
];
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

```
<template> 
  <router-view />
</template>

<script setup> 

</script>

<style scoped> 
</style>
```

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import router from "./router";
import "./style.css";
import App from "./App.vue";

createApp(App)
    .use(router)
    .mount("#app");
```

```
<template>
    Home
</template>

<script setup>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `component` value, it's a string, it should be a reference to your `Home` import:

```
import Home from '../views/Home.vue' 
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "home",
    component: Home, // <---- use Home, not "Home"
  },
];
```

Give it a go.

Comment:  Yes Thats it